# What would make css to stop working after starting Vue in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel

I am working on a laravel project and had written some CSS codes in`app.css`. When I started building Vue components, the app.css codes stopped being rendered. The file is being fetched as `<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">.` The CSS does not reflect but font-awesome icons which are fetched in the same way are appearing. What could make this happen?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly I will make a couple of assumptions and give what I think may have happened.

I read you edited app.css and then worked with your compiled system.

I am guessing you did this via `npm run dev` or a variation there of.

Upon doing this, it writes a new app.css file based on your app.scss file.

So, I am thinking that when you compiled your app you wiped out app.css as it should and rewrote the `app.css` with the build out of `app.scss`.

You should be having your css in `app.scss` or in a file that `@import` that file.

And to then to compile your css with `npm run dev`, `npm run prod`, or `npm run watch`

If you want to mix in css with app.scss you can either use the `@import` mentioned above or combine them via webpack.

To add font awesome to the app.css you do so with:

1. `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
2. Add the following to `app.scss`:

```
// Font Awesome
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

3. Compile with `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#sass

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#plain-css

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have checked the  `app.css` file and all the code I had added was deleted. I have made a `_custom.scss` file and imported it in the app.scss. I have compiled and the changes have appeared. Thanks again for the explanation